# Why do we want or need cross-norms on tensor products?

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, banach-spaces, tensor-products, topological-vector-spaces

If $(E, \|\cdot\|_1),(F, \|\cdot\|_2)$ are Banach spaces, their (algebraic) tensor product $E \otimes F$ is a vector space looking forward to be normed. A norm on a tensor product of vector spaces is called *cross-norm* if it behaves multliplicative on elementary tensors, i.e. for all $x \in E, y \in F$ we have
$$
\|x \otimes y\| = \|x\|_1 \|y\|_2. \tag{1}
$$

Prominent examples of cross-norms are the [projective $\pi$ and injective $\varepsilon$ tensor product.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_tensor_product)

In my lecture notes I found that it is *preferable* to use cross-norms on tensor products. Somewhere else I found that one wants cross-norms since they are compatible with convergent sequences. This last staement does not convince me since I find it more natural to require only
$$
\|x \otimes y\| \leq \|x\|_1 \|y\|_2 \tag{2}.
$$
I think we all agree that a *useful* norm on a tensor product should fulfill (2): If $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$, inequality $(2)$ implies that $x_n \otimes y_n \to x \otimes y$.

I have yet to find some occasion where I really need a norm fulfilling (1) and just (2) being not enough.

What do you think:

- <s>**Are cross-norms not only pretty but indispensable?**</s>. This should be taken care of by the addition I provided below: It seems natural to want the algebraic tensor product of the duals to be "included" in the dual of the algebraic tensor product, i.e. $E^* \otimes F^* \subseteq (E \otimes^\sim F)^*$ (if we identify a functional $\varphi \otimes \psi$ with its continuous extension to the completion $\cdot^\sim$ of $E \otimes F$ w.r.t. the cross-norm) although I am not capable of anticipating the consequences if this inclusion does not hold: **What are the downsides of not having this inclusion? -- Is it reasonable not to use *reasonable cross-norms*?** I think that $E^* \otimes F^*$ can be a nice point separating subspace of $(E \otimes^\sim F)^*$ but I am not sure about it.
- **Can you provide examples of important norms for tensor products (of Banach spaces) that aren't (reasonable) cross-norms?**

---

Some more thoughts: Looking at Ryan's *Introduction to Tensor Products* p.127, **reasonable** norms on $E \otimes F$ are cross-norms in the sense of (1):

> Let $(E,\|\cdot\|_1$ and $(F, \|\cdot\|_2)$ be Banach spaces. A norm $\|\cdot\|_\alpha$ on $E \otimes F$ is called *reasonable cross-norm* if
>
> 1. Inequality (2) holds.
> 2. For all $\varphi \in E^*$ and $\psi \in Y^*$, the linear functional $\varphi \otimes \psi$ on $X \otimes Y$ is bounded with operator norm
>      $$
>    \|\varphi \otimes \psi\| \leq \|\varphi\| \|\psi\|.
>    $$

Then, in proposition 6.1 it is proved that each reasonable cross-norm fulfills (1) automatically.

---

In Category theory, there seems to be the concept of **uniform cross norms**, see [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+product+of+Banach+spaces) but from the definition there it is not clear why they call it uniform *cross norm* and not just uniform tensor product norm or something else.

Comment: The only thing which comes to my mind is that for Banach algebras it is useful to have $|xy|=|x| |y|$ (which does not always hold, for sure), because this implies that they have no zero divisors.

Comment: @el_tenedor: Soon you're ready to provide a full answer for all of us.. : )

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this cross-norm property is important because it is precisely how the induced norm behaves in the case of the [tensor product of Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces). If $H_1 ≔ (U, +_U, ⋅_U, ⟨⋅∣⋅⟩_{H_1})$ and $H_2 ≔ (V, +_V, ⋅_V, ⟨⋅∣⋅⟩_{H_2})$  are Hilbert spaces over a field , then $H₁⊗H₂$ is also a Hilbert space whose inner product is induced by

$$ ⟨u_1⊗v_1∣u_2⊗v_2⟩_{H_1⊗H_2} ≔ ⟨u_1∣u_2⟩_{H_1}⋅⟨v_1∣v_2⟩_{H_2} $$

This is the unique natural choice if you insist that $⟨u_i⊗v_j∣u_k⊗v_l⟩ = δ_{ik}δ_{jl}$ when $(u_i)$ and $(v_j)$ are orthogonal bases of $H_1$ and $H_2$ repectively.

Answer (score 1):

Having a cross norm gives you separate continuity of the map $(\cdot)\otimes(\cdot): V\times V \to V\otimes V$. Fix a $w$ and take $\epsilon>0$. We want to see that there exists $\delta$ s.t. if $\|(v,w)- (v’,w)\|_{V\times V}<\delta$, then $\|v\otimes w - v’\otimes w \|_{V\otimes V}<\delta$

Assume $V$ is finite-dimensional and normed. Require $\|(v,w)- (v’,w)\|_{V\times V} = \|(v-v’,w)\|_{V\times V} < \delta$.

Let C be a constant of equivalence between the product space norm and the $L^1$-norm
Then if $\delta:= \epsilon^{0.5 } C^{-1} $, we get:

$$\|v\otimes w - v’\otimes w \|_{V\otimes V} \\
 = \|(v-v’)\otimes w  \|_{V\otimes V} \\
\leq   \|(v-v’)  \|_{V} \|w \|_{V} \\
< \max \{\|(v-v’)  \|_{V}, \|w \|_{V} \} ^2 \\
< C^2  \|(v-v’,w)\|_{V\times V} ^2 \\
< C^2\epsilon^{0.5 \cdot 2} C^{-2} \\
< \epsilon $$

This gives you half of the (in)equality for cross norms, the other half comes from the projection maps being continuous, and I will leave it for another time